# Loop through pandas dataframe, insert recipient and dataframe into Outlook e-mail

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, outlook

How do I loop through a pandas dataframe based on unique values in a column and insert into seperate Outlook e-mails?

Here is my code:

```
def Emailer(subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody =  """Lots of text"""
    attachment = 'C:/Users/Documents/file.pdf'
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
    mail.Display(True)

Emailer('subject', "multiple e-mails")
```

Here is my dataframe that I want to loop through and insert into each individual e-mail.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=list('AB'))
df['Email'] = np.random.choice(['john@mail.com', 'mark@mail.com', 'tina@mail.com'], 10)

          A         B          Email
0 -0.740284  0.509764  mark@mail.com
1  0.119413 -1.270088  mark@mail.com
2  1.792915 -0.243748  mark@mail.com
3  0.181352 -1.949043  tina@mail.com
4 -0.172640  0.051009  john@mail.com
5  0.627760 -0.038189  tina@mail.com
6 -0.589791 -3.255643  tina@mail.com
7  1.654046  0.855315  tina@mail.com
8  2.213134 -0.266334  mark@mail.com
9 -0.907995  0.880413  mark@mail.com
```

Let's say for Tina, her mail will be like this. The loop takes out rows from `df['Email']` and inserts the dataframe into the `mail.HtmlBody`, and a value from `Email` into `mail.To = recipient`. Furthermore, I want Mark and John to have e-mails with similar structure. Subject would be the same for each e-mail. Only "To" and "Body" would be different depending on the e-mail.

```
To: tina@mail.com
Subject: subject
Body:

Lots of text

          A         B          Email
3  0.181352 -1.949043  tina@mail.com
5  0.627760 -0.038189  tina@mail.com
6 -0.589791 -3.255643  tina@mail.com
7  1.654046  0.855315  tina@mail.com
```

Edit:
I made a for loop that split the dataframe into unique tables:

```
for email, df_email in df.groupby('Email'):
    print(df_email)

          A         B          Email
 4 -0.17264  0.051009  john@mail.com
          A         B          Email
0 -0.740284  0.509764  mark@mail.com
1  0.119413 -1.270088  mark@mail.com
2  1.792915 -0.243748  mark@mail.com
8  2.213134 -0.266334  mark@mail.com
9 -0.907995  0.880413  mark@mail.com
          A         B          Email
3  0.181352 -1.949043  tina@mail.com
5  0.627760 -0.038189  tina@mail.com
6 -0.589791 -3.255643  tina@mail.com
7  1.654046  0.855315  tina@mail.com
```

Comment: `df['Email'].unique()` should get you unique emails. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @pnv I am not sure how to create for loops that creates individual e-mails with dataframes.

Comment: @Ben.T No, the subject would be the same for each e-mail. Only "To" and "Body" would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [pandas dataframe.to_string](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) to create a readable string from your dataframe. Then you can do something like:

```
for i in df['Email'].unique():
    create_mail(i)
```

(create_mail being whatever function makes your e-mail on Outlook). In this situation, you'll need to add

```
df[df['Email'] == i].to_string()
```

to the mail.HtmlBody.

On another note, [df.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) may also be worth a try.

Comment: Looks like a good start! I only need to repair the dataframe when it is converted to html.